# If σ is a cycle of length n, then σ^r is also a cycle if and only if n and r are relatively prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

If σ=(1.2.3), σσσ= identity permutation, which is cyclic

in this case n=3 and r=3

but their gcd is not 1.

I don't understand why  -> this direction of theorem is true

Answer (score 3):

By relabelling, we may suppose $\sigma = (1,2,\ldots, n)$.  Thus $\sigma(i) \equiv i+1 \mod n$.  Then $\sigma^r(i) \equiv i+r \mod n$.  This is not an $n$-cycle iff there is some $i$, $1 \le i \le n$, and some $k$, $1 \le k \le n-1$, such that $\sigma^{rk}(i) = i$.  That
says $i + r k \equiv i \mod n$, i.e. $r k \equiv 0 \mod n$.
If $g = \gcd(r,n) > 1$, this will be true for $k = n/g$, but if $g = 1$, $r k \equiv 0 \mod n$ implies $k \equiv 0 \mod n$.

Comment: What about the case n=3 ,r=3. It's still a cycle but gcd is not 1

Comment: In this case $\sigma^r$ is not a cycle, it's the identity permutation.  The identity permutation is only a cycle if $n=1$.

Comment: I thought that identity permutation is cycle

Comment: If you want to call the identity permutation a cycle, then the theorem should say that if $\sigma$ is an $n$-cycle, then $\sigma^r$ is an $n$-cycle if and only if $n$ and $r$ are relatively prime.

Answer (score -1):

After working through the problem, I think you are right that $\gcd(n,r)=1$ for $\sigma^r$ to be a cycle.

The example you provided isn't a counter example because the identity isn't a cycle.

Instead, it is a product of cycles (each containing one element of $A$). So our condition holds true.

Because $\gcd(n,r)=3$ in the example you described, we don't get a cycle, as the theorem predicts.